# restart policy in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In docker compose, I want to auto restart the container if it is stop, I do this:

```
deploy:                                                                                                                   
  restart_policy:                                                                                                           
    condition: unless-stopped
```

But there is a warning that it is a docker swarm feature.

How can I do it without swarm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use something like :

```
services:
  test:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
```

see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart)